# Impossible to configure LDAP correctly in JBoss 7.1

Tags: java, jboss, ldap, jboss7.x

I have to configure LDAP authentication under JBoss 7.1 but I face an issue when I try to use my credentials. My configuration is like that:

```
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule" flag="required">
    <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
    <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://domain.com:389"/>
    <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
    <module-option name="java.naming.referral" value="follow"/>
    <module-option name="baseFilter" value="(uid={0})"/>
    <module-option name="baseCtxDN" value="ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com"/>
    <module-option name="throwValidateError" value="true"/>
    <module-option name="principalDNPrefix" value="suid="/>
    <module-option name="principalDNSuffix" value=",ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com"/>
    <module-option name="searchTimeLimit" value="5000"/>
    <module-option name="searchScope" value="ONELEVEL"/>
</login-module>
```

"uid" represents username used to login ("surname name") and "suid" represents an unique id.
So, when I try to use LDAP in my Java class like that, it works:

```
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put("java.naming.provider.url", "ldap://domain.com:389");
env.put("java.naming.security.authentication", "simple");
env.put("java.naming.security.principal", "suid=123456789001234,ou=people,dc=st,dc=com");
env.put("java.naming.referral", "follow");
env.put("java.naming.security.credentials", "123456");
DirContext directoryContext = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

But, I can't configure how JBoss has to transform uid to suid ("surname name" to "123456789001234" for example).

Comment: Off topic: belongs on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

In your LDAP server create next hierarchy:

```
+ o=your-organization-name (partition) 
   + ou=users (organizationalUnit) 
      - uid=your-id-user (inetOrgPerson), add userPassword attribute 
   + ou=groups (organizationalUnit) 
      - cn=your-user-role (groupOfNames), add the uid before created
```

security-domain on JBoss 7.1 (standalone.xml):

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">
            <security-domains>
             ...
 <security-domain name="SecurityRealm" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
                            <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldap://host-ldap-server:port-ldap-server/"/>
                            <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple"/>
                            <module-option name="principalDNPrefix" value="uid="/>
                            <module-option name="principalDNSuffix" value=",ou=users,o=your-organization-name"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesCtxDN" value="ou=groups,o=your-organization-name"/>
                            <module-option name="uidAttributeID" value="member"/>
                            <module-option name="matchOnUserDN" value="true"/>
                            <module-option name="roleAttributeID" value="cn"/>
                            <module-option name="roleAttributeIsDN" value="false"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
```

in your jboss-web.xml

```
<security-domain>SecurityRealm</security-domain>
```

and the most important: is the user allowed to access to this page? (web.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- Protected Areas -->
    <security-constraint>
         <display-name>Protected</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>              
            <url-pattern>url-pages-you-want-protect</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
            <http-method>POST</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>your-user-role</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <!-- Validation By Form -->
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>your-login-page</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>your-error-page</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <!-- Allowed Roles -->
    <security-role>
        <role-name>your-user-role</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

to test the connection use this:

```
public class LoginModulesTestCase extends TestCase
{
   static
   {
      try
      {
         Configuration.setConfiguration(new TestConfig());
         System.out.println("Installed TestConfig as JAAS Configuration");
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
   /** Hard coded login configurations for the test cases. The configuration
    name corresponds to the unit test function that uses the configuration.
    */
   static class TestConfig extends Configuration
   {
      public void refresh()
      {
      }

      public AppConfigurationEntry[] getAppConfigurationEntry(String name)
      {
         AppConfigurationEntry[] entry = null;
         try
         {
            Class[] parameterTypes = {};
            Method m = getClass().getDeclaredMethod(name, parameterTypes);
            Object[] args = {};
            entry = (AppConfigurationEntry[]) m.invoke(this, args);
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
         }
         return entry;
      }

      AppConfigurationEntry[] testLdapExample1()
      {
         String name = "org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule";
         HashMap options = new HashMap();
         options.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
         options.put("java.naming.provider.url", "ldap://host-ldap-server:port-ldap-server/");
         options.put("java.naming.security.authentication", "simple");
         options.put("principalDNPrefix", "uid=");
         options.put("principalDNSuffix", ",ou=users,o=your-organization-name");         
         options.put("rolesCtxDN", "ou=groups,o=your-organization-name");
         options.put("uidAttributeID", "member");
         options.put("matchOnUserDN", "true");
         options.put("roleAttributeID", "cn");
         options.put("roleAttributeIsDN", "false");
         AppConfigurationEntry ace = new AppConfigurationEntry(name,
         AppConfigurationEntry.LoginModuleControlFlag.REQUIRED, options);
         AppConfigurationEntry[] entry = {ace};
         return entry;
      }
   }

   public LoginModulesTestCase(String testName)
   {
      super(testName);
   }

   @Test
   public void testLdapExample1() throws Exception
   {
      System.out.println("testLdapExample1");
      UsernamePasswordHandler handler = new UsernamePasswordHandler("your-uid", "your-uid-password".toCharArray());
      LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("testLdapExample1", handler);
      lc.login();

      Subject subject = lc.getSubject();
      System.out.println("Subject: "+subject);

      Set groups = subject.getPrincipals(Group.class);
      assertTrue("Principals contains your-uid", subject.getPrincipals().contains(new SimplePrincipal("your-uid")));
      Group roles = (Group) groups.iterator().next();
      assertTrue("your-uid-role is a role", roles.isMember(new SimplePrincipal("your-uid-role")));

      lc.logout();
   }

}
```

hey I have to ask you something:

- is your ldap host = domain.com?
- and your ldap port = 389?
- where is your ldap server installed?
- is your organization's ldap partition ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com?
- don't use suid, use uid like the example I had shown you, the uid is unique
- is your uid located on ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com?
- is this code an example copy?
- I'm using Apache Directory server as lpad server on my own machine,
  who is your server?
- where your server located?

if you want I can help you to configure Apache Directory Server, you only have to ask a stackoverflow question and add the jboss 7.x and ldap stackoverflow tags

Comment: I am sorry but I am not allowed to modify LDAP server of my company.

Comment: you can use Apache Directory Studio and Make a New LDAP Connection to your company LDAP Server, when you are sure you have the rights params to connect, then modify the test conection I showed you and test it

Comment: OK, I managed to connect to my company's ldap server. But, to do so, I had to put:
"suid=********,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com"

in "Bind DN or user"
(where ******** represents my unique employee number.) But I can't use my "surname name" login.

Comment: you can't use you sn, id = suid=********,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=com and pass is password suid, these are the correct params

Answer (score 0):

I managed to connect with this, using jldap:

```
LDAPConnection conn = new LDAPConnection();
conn.connect("ldap.mycompany.com",389);
LDAPSearchResults searchResults = conn.search("ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com",
    LDAPConnection.SCOPE_ONE, "cn=Surname Name", null, false);
LDAPEntry entry = searchResults.next();
if (entry != null) {
    // the username is valid, lets pull out the CN from the attributes
    String cnValue = null;
    LDAPAttributeSet attrSet = entry.getAttributeSet();

    Iterator<LDAPAttribute> allAttrs = attrSet.iterator();
    while (allAttrs.hasNext()) {
        LDAPAttribute attr = allAttrs.next();
        String attrName = attr.getName();
        System.out.println(attrName);
        if (attrName.equalsIgnoreCase("suid")) {  // we got the CN
            cnValue = (String) attr.getStringValues().nextElement();
            System.out.println(cnValue);
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    if (cnValue == null) {
        // return auth failed, the username doesn't exist
    }

    // attempt a bind with CN and given password
    LDAPConnection tmp = new LDAPConnection();
    tmp.connect("ldap.mycompany.com", 389);
    tmp.bind("suid=" + cnValue + "," + "ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com", "MYPASSWORD"); 

    // <password> came from the user trying to login*/
    // return auth successful, username and password are valid
    // an LDAPException is thrown if the credentials are invalid
}
```

But I don't manage to use this for my jboss configuration.

EDIT, this works in Java:

```
String username = "surname name";

Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>(11);

boolean b = false;

env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap.mycompany.com:389");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "none");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "uid="+ username +",ou=people,dc=mycompany,dc=com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "PASS");

try {
    // Create initial context
    DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

    // Close the context when we're done
    b = true;
    ctx.close();

} catch (NamingException e) {
    b = false;
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally{
    if(b){
        System.out.print("Success");
    }else{
        System.out.print("Failure");
    }
}
```